# Capture suspend lambda parameter with generic result in a mockked class

Tags: android, junit5, mockk

I want to know if it is possible to capture an suspend lambda with generic result with MockK and JUnit5.
I've tried several ways, and in the most recent I'm having a KotlinNullPointerException when I try to run the test.

Here is the code, with the complete class dependencies and test:

```
class Test {
data class Result<out T>(val status: ResultStatus, val data: T?, val exception: Exception?) {
    companion object {
        fun <T> success(data: T?): Result<T> {
            return Result(ResultStatus.SUCCESS, data, null)
        }

        fun <T> error(exception: Exception): Result<T> {
            return Result(ResultStatus.ERROR, null, exception)
        }

        fun <T> loading(data: T? = null): Result<T> {
            return Result(ResultStatus.LOADING, data, null)
        }
    }
}

class Dep1() {
    fun <R> methodToMock(viewModelScope: CoroutineScope, block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> R): MutableLiveData<Result<R>> {
        val result = MutableLiveData<Result<R>>()
        result.value = Result.loading()

        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                var asyncRequestResult: R? = null
                withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                    asyncRequestResult = block()
                }
                result.value = Result.success(asyncRequestResult)
            } catch (cancellationException: CancellationException) {
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                result.value = Result.error(exception)
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}

class Dep2() {
    fun methodToAssert(): Boolean {
        println("Called")
        return true
    }
}

class ClassToTest(private val dep1: Dep1, private val dep2: Dep2) {
    fun methodToCall(coroutineScope: CoroutineScope): MutableLiveData<Result<Boolean>> {
        return dep1.methodToMock(coroutineScope) {
            dep2.methodToAssert()
        }
    }
}

private val dep1: Dep1 = mockk()
private val dep2: Dep2 = mockk(relaxed = true)
private val mViewModelScope: CoroutineScope = GlobalScope

@Test
fun `Check if is calling the required methods correctly`() {
    val classToTest = ClassToTest(dep1, dep2)

    val transactionLambda = slot<suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Boolean>()
    coEvery { dep1.methodToMock(mViewModelScope, capture(transactionLambda)) } coAnswers {
        MutableLiveData(Result.success(transactionLambda.captured.invoke(mViewModelScope)))
    }

    classToTest.methodToCall(mViewModelScope)

    verify { dep2.methodToAssert() }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is also having this problem, I was able to solve it using `every` instead of `coEvery` and calling the `coInvoke()` slot method:

```
every { dep1.methodToMock(mViewModelScope, capture(transactionLambda)) } answers  {
    MutableLiveData(Result.success(transactionLambda.coInvoke(mViewModelScope)))
}
```